# Using `this` in a js object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, this

I have the following js object:

```
var livePage = {
    delay: 1000,
    loadTables: function(){
        loadTable($("#vbeTable"),'getUpdateA')
        loadTable($("#vbcTable"),'getUpdateB')
        createAlertDialog();
    },
    setClicks: function(){
        $(".expand").live('click',function(){
            expand($(this).attr('expandvalue'));
        })
        $( ".launch" )
            .click(function(){
                newPopup('index.php',1120,550);
            });
        $('.edit').live('click',function(){
            openColPick($(this).attr('colType'))
        });
    },
    setRightClick: function(){
        $('body').contextMenu('mainmenu', {
              bindings: {
                'o_o': function(t) {
                  thePopupWindowsMain('oo','','',220,150,'right','');
                },
                'o_h': function(t) {
                  thePopupWindowsMain('oh','','',285,385,'left','');
                },
                'launch_prog': function(t) {
                  $(".launch").click();
                },
                'logout': function(t){
                    window.top.location = 'logout.php';
                }
              }
            });
    },
    setWindow: function(){
        $(window)
            .resize(function() {
                $('body').css('height', $(this).height())
                alertToCorner();
            })
            .scroll(function(){$(this).resize()});
        $(window).resize();
    },
    checkLogout: function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getLogin.php',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){
                if($.trim(data) == 'LOGOUT'){
                    window.location = 'logout.php';
                }
            },
            complete: function(){
                setTimeout( function () {
                    livePage.checkLogout();},
                livePage.delay)
            },
            timeout: 2000
        });
    },
    init: function(){
        this.checkLogout();
        this.loadTables();
        this.setClicks();
        this.setRightClick();
        this.setWindow();
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

For some reason in the `checkLogout: function()` I have to use `livePage.delay` and `livePage.checkLogout()`  When i try using for example `this.checklogout()` i get the following error in Chrome's Console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object
>   DOMWindow] has no method 'checkLogout'

How do i fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside a function `this` is not bound to whatever it was bound to outside anymore. The easiest solution is assigning to another var using `var self = this;` or in your case passing it via the `context: this` option of `$.ajax()`.

Comment: this worked :-) i added `var self = this;` to the top of the `checkLogout()` fn, and i used self instead of `this` thanks ^_^

Answer (score 3):

You can try,

```
 checkLogout: function(){
        var self = this; //reference to the livePage object
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getLogin.php',
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){
                if($.trim(data) == 'LOGOUT'){
                    window.location = 'logout.php';
                }
            },
            complete: function(){
                setTimeout( function () {
                    self.checkLogout();},  //need to use self because 'this' no longer refers to livePage in this context
                livePage.delay)
            },
            timeout: 2000
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is far different in js than in languages like C#.  First, it is function-scoped.  Secondly (and probably more importantly), you can control what `this` will be when calling a function.  (Check out the "call" and "apply" functions, which are used quite frequently in javascript frameworks.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a read up on [this this keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) in Javascript. In your case `this` refers to window which like the error says has no method 'checkLogout'.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `context: this` property to the hash that you send to `$.ajax` and then in the complete handler call `this.checkLogout`.

What happens is that JQuery's `ajax` method will call the handlers using the `window` as the `this` context, we can change that by adding a `context` property to the call.